# JQuery multiple id index with form submit

Tags: jquery, forms

not sure how to do this as ID's are ment to be unique but this is a dynamically  series of forms generated from a php array - based on reading the file names in a directory - with the same ID.  What I need to do is identify which form so the data can be processed.

Here is the form

```
echo '<form method="post" action="" id="frmwidget">';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo ucfirst($comments[0]);
            echo '</td><td>';   
                echo $comments[1];
            echo '</td><td align="center">';    
                echo '<input type="checkbox">';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td><td align="center">';
                echo '<input type="checkbox">';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td><td align="center">';    
                echo '<input type="checkbox">';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td><td align="center">';    
                echo '<input type="submit" id="cmdwidgets">';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
    echo '</form>';
```

And here is my start of the Jquery

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j('#cmdwidgets').live('click',function(){


alert('Your widgets will load');
```

I will want to Ajax the form in here .. not just an alert

```
$j('#wall').load("admin/inc/ajax-widgets.php");
return false;
});
});
```

Yes I know the form could be 1 form not multiples, but for this purpose it needs to be multiple forms. And yes I know the form is incomplete i.e. field names etc.

Any help/suggestions please - thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand your question, could your clarify? Are you attempting to make multiples forms: one for each file in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it another way but using a UL and indexing the li's

Answer (score 0):

The # selector hooks directly into `document.getElementById`, so will only get one element back.

To select all your forms, the following selector will suffice:

```
$("form[id='frmwidget']")
```

However, I have to ask. Why on earth, do you have dupliate ids? Have you thought about, assigning a class to each and selecting by that? i.e.

```
$("form.myclass")
```